# c# for loop arithmetic

Tags: c#

This program I am writing for a class uses "random" numbers to generate arrival(arrival[i]) and service times(service[i]) for jobs. My current problem is with the arrival time. To get the arrival time, I call a function named exponential and add the returning value to the previous arrival time (arrival[i-1]) in the array. For some reason I don't understand, the program is not using the previous value of the array for the addition, but rather a seemingly random value (1500,1600 ect). But I know the real values set in the array are all below 5. This should be simple array arithmetic in a for loop but I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{

class Program
{
    static long state;

    void putseed(int value)
    {
        state = value;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program pro = new Program();
        double totals = 0;
        double totald = 0;
        pro.putseed(12345);
        double[] arrival = new double[1000];
        double[] service = new double[1000];
        double[] wait = new double[1000];
        double[] delay = new double[1000];
        double[] departure = new double[1000];
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            arrival[i] = arrival[i - 1] + pro.Exponential(2.0);
            if (arrival[i] < departure[i - 1])
                departure[i] = departure[i] - arrival[i];
            else
                departure[i] = 0;
            service[i] = pro.Uniform((long)1.0,(long)2.0);
            totals += service[i];
            totald += departure[i];
        }
        double averages = totals / 1000;
        double averaged = totald / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n",averages);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\n", averaged);
        Console.WriteLine("press any key");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public double Random()
    {
        const long A = 48271;
        const long M = 2147483647;
        const long Q = M / A;
        const long R = M % A;
        long t = A * (state % Q) - R * (state / Q);
        if (t > 0)
            state = t;
        else
            state = t + M;
        return ((double)state / M);
    }

    public double Exponential(double u)
    {
        return (-u * Math.Log(1.0 - Random()));
    }

    public double Uniform(long a, long b)
    {
        Program pro = new Program();
        double c = ((double)a + ((double)b - (double)a) * pro.Random());
        return c;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So, what does the debugger tell you?

Comment: _is not using the previous value of the array for the addition_ - is already a conclusion (assumption) that might be wrong. Try to state the problem more clearly, actual vs expected values.

Comment: After setting array[0] to 0.0, I am still getting incorret values. The first 6 values returned by Exponential are 0.258758677353176,1.85288076211496,2.80828087927641,0.692298649867623,0.582910365473941,2.46733148844339. The values I am getting from the addition are 1937.01067024245,1937.13279342283,1937.4377070674,1937.47700375819,1938.11204641022,1938.34058799664

Answer (score 1):

The values returned by your `Exponential` method can be very big. Very very big. In fact, they tend towards infinity if your `Random` values come close to 1...

I'm not surpirised your values in the arrival array tend to be big. I would in fact expect them to.

Also: try to name your methods accordingly to what they do. Your `Exponential` method has nothing to do with a mathematical exponential.

And try not to implement a random number generator yourself. Use the `Random` class included in the .Net Framework. If you want to always have the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers (as you seem to want), you can seed it with a constant.

Comment: `Exponential` stays in the < 10 range, based on actually testing it.  +1 for the rest of the answer, though.

Comment: Due to the implementation of the Random method, the actual maximal value for Exponential is 21.48 * u . Very poor Random implementation indeed.

Comment: The random function is something I have to use for the class. I did not create it

Comment: @DavidPothier - Eww.  I take objection to your professor.  Please never use that in real live.

Comment: yeah I did not create any of the methods, I was just supposed to run the program using them

Answer (score 1):

Your output sounds perfectly correct to me, given your current logic.  Maybe your logic is flawed?

I changed the first three lines of the `for` loop to:

```
var ex = Exponential(2.0);
arrival[i] = arrival[i - 1] + ex;
Console.WriteLine("i = " + arrival[i] + ", i-1 = " + arrival[i-1] + ", Exponential = " + ex);
```

And this is the start and end of the output:

```
i = 0.650048368820785, i-1 = 0, Exponential = 0.650048368820785
i = 3.04412645597466, i-1 = 0.650048368820785, Exponential = 2.39407808715387
i = 4.11006720700818, i-1 = 3.04412645597466, Exponential = 1.06594075103352
i = 5.05503853283036, i-1 = 4.11006720700818, Exponential = 0.944971325822186
i = 6.77397334440211, i-1 = 5.05503853283036, Exponential = 1.71893481157175
i = 8.03325406790781, i-1 = 6.77397334440211, Exponential = 1.2592807235057
i = 9.99797822010981, i-1 = 8.03325406790781, Exponential = 1.964724152202
i = 10.540051694898, i-1 = 9.99797822010981, Exponential = 0.542073474788196
i = 10.6332298644808, i-1 = 10.540051694898, Exponential = 0.0931781695828122
....
i = 1970.86834655692, i-1 = 1968.91989881306, Exponential = 1.94844774386271
i = 1971.49302600885, i-1 = 1970.86834655692, Exponential = 0.62467945192265
i = 1972.16711634654, i-1 = 1971.49302600885, Exponential = 0.674090337697884
i = 1974.5740025773, i-1 = 1972.16711634654, Exponential = 2.40688623075635
i = 1978.14531015105, i-1 = 1974.5740025773, Exponential = 3.5713075737529
i = 1979.15315663014, i-1 = 1978.14531015105, Exponential = 1.00784647908321
```

The math here looks perfectly right to me.

---

Side comment: You can declare all your extra methods (`Exponential`, `Uniform`, etc) as `static`, so you don't have to create a new `Program` just to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You did not set the value of arrival[0], it is not initialized before for loop so the other values in array calculated wrongly.

Comment: `arrivals[0]` will simply be `0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Extra suggestion,

```
public double Uniform(long a, long b)
{
    double c = ((double)a + ((double)b - (double)a) * Random());
    return c;
}
```

change your Uniform function like that.